# Retaining values of drop down that are disabled after submit

Tags: php

I have this form with about 9 drop down menus. I am trying to retain the selected values after submission. My code works for 2 of those drop down menus which are not disabled, but not for the remaining 7 disabled ones. Is there a different way to write the code for those?

**1 of the 2 drop downs that isn't disabled:-**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo "<select name = 'account_name' id = 'idaname'>"; 
echo "<option value = ''>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $selected = (isset($_POST['account_name']) && $_POST['account_name'] == $row['account_name']) ? 'selected = "selected"' :'';
    ?>
    <option <?php echo $selected; ?> value = "<?php echo $row['account_name']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['account_name']; ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

**2 of the 7 disabled drop downs :-**

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT rsm_val FROM tablename2 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
echo "<select name = 'rsm_val' id = 'rsm_val' onchange = 'runrsm()' disabled >"; 
echo "<option value = '" .$rsm_val . "'>" . $rsm_val . "</option>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $selected = (isset($_POST['rsm_val']) && $_POST['rsm_val'] == $row['rsm_val']) ? 'selected = "selected"' :'';
    ?>
    <option <?php echo $selected; ?> value = "<?php echo $row['rsm_val']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['rsm_val']; ?> </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>



<select name = 'boost_app' id = 'boost_app' onchange = 'runboost()' disabled>
<?php echo "<option value = '". $boost_app . "'>" . $boost_app .  "</option>"; ?>
<option <?php if($_POST['boost_app'] == 'Yes'){?> selected="true" <?php }; ?> value = "Yes">Yes</option>
<option <?php if($_POST['boost_app'] == 'No') {?> selected="true" <?php }; ?> value = "No">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retain field values after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706179/retain-field-values-after-submit)

Comment: Why don't you try `readonly` instead of `disabled`, huh?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML form readonly SELECT tag/input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a dropdown is disabled, the value isn't sent to the server. You can add a hidden input with the same name and value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="boost_app" value="<?php echo $_POST['boost_app'];?>">
<select name = 'boost_app' id = 'boost_app' onchange = 'runboost()' disabled>
<?php echo "<option value = '". $boost_app . "'>" . $boost_app .  "</option>"; ?>
<option <?php if($_POST['boost_app'] == 'Yes'){?> selected="true" <?php }; ?> value = "Yes">Yes</option>
<option <?php if($_POST['boost_app'] == 'No') {?> selected="true" <?php }; ?> value = "No">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Okay I have some javascript, that under certain situations will turn the disabled attribute to be false(enabled). If it is enabled, I was planning to have the updated selection in that drop down, but now my update query is failing. I'm not sure how we can do that with the same name and id for the hidden field

Comment: You should remove or rename the hidden input when you enable the dropdown.

Comment: So you're saying I need to have 2 hidden inputs? Because I already have 1 like this --->  <input type = "hidden" id = "boost_app3" name = "boost_app" value = "<?php echo $boost_app; ?>" />

Comment: No, just one hidden input. But if you enable the dropdown, you need to get rid of the hidden input, so you don't have two inputs with the same name.

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised it doesn't work. If there are two inputs with the same name, I think it uses the last one, so the hidden input should be ignored when the dropdown is enabled.

Comment: Make sure they don't have the same `id`, though. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: Yeah they don't have the same ID as I'm using javascript as well. But I still don't understand how can I get rid of a hidden input?

Comment: Change its name: `document.getElementById("boost_app3").name = "ignore_boost_app";`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readonly` instead:

```
<select name = 'boost_app' id = 'boost_app' onchange = 'runboost()' readonly>
<?php echo "<option value = '". $boost_app . "'>" . $boost_app .  "</option>"; ?>
<option <?php if($_POST['boost_app'] == 'Yes'){?> selected="true" <?php }; ?> value = "Yes">Yes</option>
<option <?php if($_POST['boost_app'] == 'No') {?> selected="true" <?php }; ?> value = "No">No</option>
</select>
```

This will not allow user to edit values, and will send the data with form submission too. [Learn more about it](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp).

**Edit:** And if `readonly` doesn't work for the `<select>` tag, then you can `disable` all options except the selected 1. Like:

```
<select name = 'boost_app' id = 'boost_app' onchange = 'runboost()'>
<?php echo "<option value = '". $boost_app . "' disabled>" . $boost_app .  "</option>"; ?>
<option <?php if($_POST['boost_app'] == 'Yes'){?> selected="true" <?php }else{echo "disabled";} ?> value = "Yes">Yes</option>
<option <?php if($_POST['boost_app'] == 'No') {?> selected="true" <?php }else{echo "disabled";} ?> value = "No">No</option>
</select>
```

Or you can have a `hidden` input with the same name, Like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="boost_app" value="<?=$_POST['boost_app']?>">
<select name = 'boost_app' id = 'boost_app' onchange = 'runboost()' disabled>
<?php echo "<option value = '". $boost_app . "'>" . $boost_app .  "</option>"; ?>
<option <?php if($_POST['boost_app'] == 'Yes'){?> selected="true" <?php }; ?> value = "Yes">Yes</option>
<option <?php if($_POST['boost_app'] == 'No') {?> selected="true" <?php }; ?> value = "No">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't think you can have readonly for select menu. i just tried it and the user can change selections in the drop down

Comment: Looking at the hidden input fields, I have some javascript, that under certain situations will turn the disabled attribute to be false(enabled). If so, I was planning to have the updated selection in that drop down, but now my update query isn't working. I'm not sure how we can do that with the same name and id for the hidden field

Comment: @abc you can try something like this `$('input[name=boost_app]').attr("disabled", true);` to disable the hidden input when select is enabled and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to make the dropdown displayed as if it 'disabled'

> $(#boost_app).css({"background-color":"rgb(238, 238, 238)", "pointer-events":"none"}).keydown(false)